# Understanding why pure CSS parallax effect works with div, but not body tag?

Tags: html, css, parallax, css-transforms

I am trying to understand the Pure CSS Parallax effect Keith Clark demonstrates on his website [in this article](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/).

Take these two jsFiddles: [CSS Parallax with div](http://jsfiddle.net/oyja5326/) and [CSS Parallax with body](http://jsfiddle.net/61c70j55/).

The first one works as described, the second one does not - and no parallax effect occurs. The only difference between these two documents is that the first one lacks an intermmediatary `div.parallax` tag with the following properties:

```
.parallax {
      perspective: 1px;
      height: 800px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 }
```

While the second one removes this tag and adds the above styles to the body:

```
body {
      perspective: 1px;
      height: 800px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 }
```

Can anyone tell me why this occurs? Why do I need a seemingly redundant tag in my document for this effect to occur? Why can't the body element act as the `div.parallax` container element?

Comment: You really ought to put the CSS in jsFiddle's CSS panel and remove the boilerplate markup, otherwise it's pretty pointless to host the code there when it's all just one self-contained HTML document.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because the values for `overflow` on the body are transferred to the root element, leaving the body with the default `overflow: visible` and breaking the transform. See [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) of the spec.

Setting `overflow: hidden` on the root element will prevent this behavior and allow the body to function as the container.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for this.